Keyboard/mouse automation with headless sway
I want to automate testing on an application that is running inside a headless sway which I'm starting like this:
SWAYSOCK=/tmp/sway-ipc.sock \
WLR_LIBINPUT_NO_DEVICES=1 \
WLR_BACKENDS=headless \
WLR_RENDERER=pixman \
WLR_RENDERER_ALLOW_SOFTWARE=1 \
sway --config=custom-sway.conf

I am able to start applications inside that and verify that they are indeed running by running a screenshot utility (grim) inside that headless sway session. Now I want to control the application with a script to create a test for my software. I have trouble producing any mouse clicks or key presses.
Usually, dogtail worked but it seems to have trouble with wayland: https://gitlab.com/dogtail/dogtail/-/issues/3
If I try using dogtail, it finds the application and the button (according to the output of
dogtail.tree.root.dump()) but the click events it generates are at impossible coordinates.
I found ydotool and tried to manually click at the coordinate that I found by investigating the screenshot but the click it generated seems to have had no effect.
I had a similar experience with wtype which claims to have produced an event but according to the screenshot I took, the keypress had no effect.
What is the usual way to automate applications inside headless sway for automation purposes?
